# Deserializing an array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, json, xamarin.forms.listview

I am having difficult de-serializing the following JSON

```
[{"JobID": 397597,"CustomerId": "ENV"},
 {"JobID": 397694,"CustomerId": "UNI015"},
 {"JobID": 397836,"CustomerId": "AMA003"}]
```

```
JobData Class
   public class JobData
    {
        [JsonProperty("JobID")]
        public int JobID;
        [JsonProperty("CustomerId")]
        public string CustomerId;
    }
```

This is the REST Service class

```
    public class RESTService
    {
        readonly HttpClient _client;

        public RESTService()
        {
            _client = new HttpClient();
        }

        public async Task<List<JobData>> GetJobData(string query)
        {
            List<JobData> jobData = null;
            try
            {
                var response = await _client.GetAsync(query);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    jobData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JobData>>(content);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("\t\tERROR {0}", ex.Message);
            }

            return jobData;
        }
    }
}
```

I wish to read the JSON response into a Xamarin Listview but no data is returned. The content variable returns a valid JSON string.

Comment: i'm confused by that `[JsonProperty("SiteID")]`

Comment: **Edit** menu -> **Paste Special** -> **Paste JSON As Classes**  public fields are not the same as properties

Comment: [Could not reproduce the issue](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xhJv1n). Please, post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And remove `[JsonProperty("SiteID")]`.

Comment: I changed the JsonProperty to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure it in the Startup.cs class with `services.AddNewtonsoftJson();`

As second I would initialize JobData. `var jobData = new List<JobData>();` This is better than using `null`.

If this doesn't work, debug the program and look what `var content` contains. If you know what `content` contains, it can bring you a lot further.

Comment: JsonConvert is from Newtonsoft

Comment: This is what the var content contains  [0:] [{"JobID":397831,"CustomerId":"SELECT"},{"JobID":397613,"CustomerId":"SELECT"},{"JobID":397614,"CustomerId":"SELECT"}]

Comment: With CustomerId is something wrong. In your question you have different values. Also maybe try `jobData = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JobData[]>(content)).ToList();`